# How to use or install pycocoevalcap?

Tags: python, tensorflow, module, pip, pycocotools

I'm new to use coco Datasets .. i got this error

```
# this requires the coco package, Link
  from pycocoevalcap.bleu.bleu import Bleu
  from pycocoevalcap.rouge.rouge import Rouge
  from pycocoevalcap.cider.cider import Cider 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pycocoevalcap'
```

i downloaded coco package with the given Link and tried to use `pip3 install pycocoevalcap`

but got

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pycocoevalcap (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pycocoevalcap
```

How  can i fix it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I used this command:

```
 pip install "git+https://github.com/salaniz/pycocoevalcap.git"
```

and it returned

```
 Collecting git+https://github.com/salaniz/pycocoevalcap.git
  Cloning https://github.com/salaniz/pycocoevalcap.git to /tmp/pip-req-build-3u0sbfzy
  Running command git clone -q https://github.com/salaniz/pycocoevalcap.git /tmp/pip-req-build-3u0sbfzy
Collecting pycocotools>=2.0.0
 ...
Successfully built pycocoevalcap pycocotools
Installing collected packages: cython, pycocotools, pycocoevalcap.
Successfully installed cython-0.29.20 pycocoevalcap-1.1 pycocotools-2.0.1
```

Comment: thanks for the link .. i'm stuck in this lines   Running command git clone -q https://github.com/salaniz/pycocoevalcap /tmp/pip-req-build-ejcbdzsv
and didn't give me anything

Comment: yes it takes some time, just leave it there for few minutes